# Is there a diagonal matrix D such that DMD is SDD, where M is SPD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-graph-theory, matrix-product

Let $M$ be symmetric and positive definite matrix (SPD). It is known [1] that

**if** $M$ is SPD and 
in addition satisfies $M_{ij}\leq 0$, for $i\neq j$ (called M-matrix) 
 
**then** there is a **positive diagonal** matrix $D$ such that 
$DMD$ is symmetric, **diagonally dominant** and $M_{ij}\leq 0$ (called SDDM matrix).

**Q1**: Let $M$ be SPD. Is there a **diagonal** matrix $D^{\prime}$ with $D^{\prime}_{ii} \neq 0~~ \forall i$ such that 
$D^{\prime}MD^{\prime}$ is symmetric and **diagonally dominant** matrix?

**Q2**: Let $M$ be SPD and $[M\mathbf{1}]_i\leq[\mathrm{diag}(M)\mathbf{1}]_i~~\forall i$ (a weaker condition than $M_{ij}\leq 0$). 
Is there a **diagonal** matrix $D^{\prime}$ with $D^{\prime}_{ii} \neq 0~~ \forall i$ such that 
$D^{\prime}MD^{\prime}$ is symmetric and **diagonally dominant** matrix?

**Q3**: Is there a matrix $D^\prime$ from above such that all entries $D^{\prime}_{ii} \neq 0$ belong to 
 a **bounded** range, say $[-1,1]\backslash{\{0\}}$.

[1]: Topics in Matrix Analysis
http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511840371

Comment: This question probably fits better at math.se or mathoverflow.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195875 .